# Triangular array of non-independent elements each row

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, weak-convergence, probability-limit-theorems

When doing my research, I end up with examining the behavior of row-wise average of the following triangular array.

Let $A_n\stackrel{iid}{\sim} Bern(\pi)$, $Y_n\stackrel{iid}{\sim} N(\mu, \sigma^2)$, and $\pi_n=\dfrac{A_1+A_2+...+A_n}{n}$. Consider the following triangular array:

$\dfrac{A_1Y_1}{\pi_1}$

$\dfrac{A_1Y_1}{\pi_2}$, $\dfrac{A_2Y_2}{\pi_2}$

$\dfrac{A_1Y_1}{\pi_3}$, $\dfrac{A_2Y_2}{\pi_3}$, $\dfrac{A_3Y_3}{\pi_3}$

...

$\dfrac{A_1Y_1}{\pi_n}$, $\dfrac{A_2Y_2}{\pi_n}$, ..., $\dfrac{A_nY_n}{\pi_n}$

Let $Z_n$ is the average of row $n$. **Does sequence $Z_n$ converge** (a.s., in probability, or in distribution) to anything?

Comment: Just to be clear, $Z_n := \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n A_i Y_i}{\sum_{i=1}^n A_i}$? It seems you can just define this without mentioning the triangular array.

Comment: I feel like the cases where $\pi_n = 0$ are problematic.

Comment: For your first comment, indeed, we can write like that. I make here a simplified version of my big problem. For the second, If, e.g., $\pi=0.5$, then $P(\pi_n=0)$ when $n$ is sufficiently large is very very small.

Answer (score 0):

From the law of large numbers we have that,
\begin{align}
\pi_n \xrightarrow[]{p} \pi.
\end{align}
Similarly we have,
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}A_iY_i \xrightarrow{p} \mathbb{E}[A_1Y_1].
\end{align}
Now if $A_i$ and $Y_j$ are independent for all $i$ and $j$ then $\mathbb{E}[A_1Y_1] = \mathbb{E}[A_1]\mathbb{E}[Y_1] = \pi\mu$. This can also be interpreted as convergence in distribuiton, albeit with a degenerate distribution. Then, your situation fits with [Slutsky's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slutsky%27s_theorem) and we have,
\begin{align}
\frac{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}A_iY_i}{\pi_n} \xrightarrow{d} \frac{\pi\mu}{\pi} = \mu.
\end{align}

I believe that convergence in distribution towards a degenerate distribution, implies convergence in probability to the constant in the degenerate distribution. If you are concerned with dividing to zero, you can pad the numerator of $\pi_n$ with an arbitrarily small value $\delta>0$.